# Error updating WordPress, does not ask for FTP password, just error

Tags: errors, updates

I started to update a WordPress blog and ran into a permissions problem. I fixed the permissions problem and started the update again and at some point (been a few days now), I received the following error. I tried again this morning and updating plugins or the program itself yields the same error.

Update WordPress
Downloading update from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.7.1-new-bundled.zip…

Download failed.: Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.

Installation Failed

I have a couple of blogs on the same web hosting account and neither of the other ones have issues, just this blog.

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? Have you [hard-coded connection credentials](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120387/21376) into `wp-config.php`?

Comment: I added the database connection information into the wp-config.php file, but not the FTP. The WordPress blog always asked for my FTP credentials, just now now. My suspicion is probably that the site got partially updated and that is causing an error, maybe not. Oh, what do you mean by debugging information? I gave the entire error message above. Is there more somewhere to be had? I did not change any file to add debug information.

Comment: To enable debugging ___follow the link___. That looks like a user-friendly system message. I expect that there is more debugging data to be had.

Comment: Adding in the debug option, WP_DEBUG set to true, causes a "Internal Server Error" message in Google Chrome, so I had to revert back to false.

Comment: You did it incorrectly then, probably a syntax error.